# Stop an animated square with button

Tags: ios, animation, swift, uiview

i'm trying to stop a square animated in a view (up and down in loop) with a button and read the position (x, y)
this is the code for the movement

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    while buttonPress == false {
    movement()
    }
}

func movement() {
    coloredSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    coloredSquare.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:500, width:50, height:50)
    self.view.addSubview(coloredSquare)
    movementDown()
}

func movementDown() {
    // lets set the duration to 1.0 seconds
    // and in the animations block change the background color
    // to red and the x-position  of the frame
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
        self.coloredSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        self.coloredSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 500, width: 50, height: 50)
        }, completion: { animationFinished in
            self.movementUp()
    })
}

func movementUp() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
        self.coloredSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.coloredSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        }, completion: { animationFinished in
            self.movementDown()
    })
}
```

if i try whit WHILE to do a method until the condition is false, Xcode build but the simulator stop at the launch screen, if i cancel the while condition, the animation work but nothing stop it...
can anyone help me?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, get rid of the while loop. In the completion block of the animations, first check if the animation was completed before you call the other animation -- if you cancel the animation, it won't be true, so the animations will stop. In your button method, you need to access the coloredSquare's presentation layer to get its current position, and cancel all animations to make the animation stop immediately.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var coloredSquare: UIView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    [self .movement()];
}


func movement() {

    coloredSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    coloredSquare.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:500, width:50, height:50)

    self.view.addSubview(coloredSquare)

    movementDown()
}

func movementDown() {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
        self.coloredSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        self.coloredSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 500, width: 50, height: 50)
        }, completion: { animationFinished in
            if animationFinished {
                self.movementUp()
            }
    })
}

func movementUp() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
        self.coloredSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.coloredSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        }, completion: { animationFinished in
            if animationFinished {
                self.movementDown()
            }
    })
}



@IBAction func stopBlock(sender: AnyObject) {
    var layer = coloredSquare.layer.presentationLayer() as CALayer
    var frame = layer.frame
    println(frame)
    coloredSquare.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    coloredSquare.frame = frame // You need this to keep the block where it was when you cancelled the animation, otherwise it will jump to the position defined by the end of the current animation
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Because your while loop is not able to be broken out of.

You are stuck in an infinite loop that cannot be broken.

It is impossible for `buttonPress` == `true`.

You need to be checking for the buttonPress within the while loop.

However, I would not advise doing this method at all.

Instead here is what you should do:

Create an animation that brings the square up. Have it fire a callback when that animation is complete, and have it animate the square to the bottom. This way you dont have to use a while loop.

While loops can be VERY dangerous on the main thread (as you are currently seeing).

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a function that gets called periodically so the system does not get locked waiting for your while loop to end.

You can setup a Timer to run your `animation` like this:

```
NSTimer *animationTimer;
NSTimeInterval animationInterval = 1.0 / 30.0;

- (void) startAnimation{
    animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:animationInterval target:self selector:@selector(animate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void) stopAnimation{
    [animationTimer invalidate];
    animationTimer = nil;
}

- (void) animate {
    NSLog(@"do your animation here..");
}
```